Uploading media from non-local host computer
I am working on a Wordpress site that is locally hosted on another computer. I have admin privileges so I should be able to make the changes I need, but I am having trouble uploading new media. I keep getting the error: "Unable to upload media... Is its parent directory writable by the server?". I assume that this is because I am on a different computer than the one that it is hosted on locally. Is there a way that I bypass this? If not, can I somehow also locally host the website to be able to upload media from my computer?
Thanks for the help!

It's not an issue with accessing it from another computer: when you think about it all web servers are another computer. The user PHP runs as on the computer hosting the site needs to have write permission to the directory that WordPress is in (and all subdirectories). Exactly how to achieve that depends on a number of factors: what the operating system is, how PHP is running (Apache module vs FCGI or PHP-FPM).
If you just want to set up a local development copy of WP on your own without troubleshooting the existing environment, LocalWP is a good tool. It also integrates with WP Engine hosting.
